# Download ,Installing and delete the apk file from server not from the marketplace .How to do Pragmatically in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, apk

There is use case  like certain customers can download our apk file  from our server. The apk file will be downloaded to the device first. Maybe in /sdcard. After the Installation ,app should be remained in the mobile but APK file should be deleted .

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Where should the app be deleted? On the mobile? Why would the user then install it? On the server? Then this is no android related question, but rather about running some server side scripts that hand out individual copies

Comment: The question is ok. The .apk will be downloaded to the device first. Maybe in /sdcard. Then it has to be installed. After that the .apk file in /sdcard can be deleted. The app stays installed with that. But indeed the poster could have explained it better... The app should not be deleted but the .apk file.

Comment: The main Reason for this use case is customers should not share the apk file to others .